# Restore suddenly lost toolbarbuttons, toolstrip, statusbuttons, menu bars from existing c# project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017

During working on a c# project in Visual Studio 2017 menu and toolstrip items began suddenly to disappear from my project step wise with the underlying source code. I think someone accessed through a network share and deleted them, if there isn't any other technical reason for this in place.
A little later I recognized that my project has all toolbars, menubars and
statusbars and everything else dynamic missing on its form (Windows Forms).

Stats of my system: Win7 64Bit Pro SP1, VS 2017 (newest Update) with help files and all additions, using Net Framework 4.5 (64 Bit EXE) for the particular project. References were mainly Microsoft Office 14 Interop Assemblies.

Is there by any means a possibility to restore the original project, if no backup exists on a media? I am not connected to GIT or any other versioning
software, cloud options I had off. I simply worked on a local project on a
not long ago brand new installed notebook computer (Intel Core 7).

Comment: You should always use source control such as git in order to avoid situations like that.

Comment: As Igor pointed out, use git. You can always have a local git repo without network access. Just `git init` and start tracking. It will also be a good starting point for a project that grows for tracking changes from the genesis lines of code.

Comment: Thank you Igor, Jonas so far. I will update this topic as soon I found the reason why it happened or a solution how to fix it. I still hope that at someone happened a similar issue before and maybe it is still possible to fix that.